# How to properly use "moduleDisplayString" in Veins 4.4?

Tags: c++, simulation, omnet++, veins

I have used Veins 4.4 and the simulations are executed normally.

However, I would like to change the appearance of vehicles in graphic mode. By analyzing the code, I noticed that the "moduleDisplayString" parameter is used to do this, but even using OMNeT's default DisplayString values I always get a mapping error.

```
[...]
*.manager.moduleType = "sdvn.nodes.Car"
*.manager.moduleName = "vehicle"
*.manager.moduleDisplayString = "i=misc/sun;is=vs"
[...]
```

Error message:

```
invalid syntax for mapping "i=misc/sun;is=vs" for parameter "moduleDisplayString"
```

Has anyone been able to use this parameter correctly?

Comment: what do you mean by "appearance of vehicles"? Their shape in OMNeT++ Tkenv, or the shape in SUMO gui? Or something completely different?

Comment: I was looking for OMNeT++ Qtenv. But analyzing the TraCIMobility.cc, on method updateDisplayString(), I notice that the graphic appearance is hard-coded. I'll probably have to create a new mobility class inheriting TraCIMobility and change the updateDisplayString behavior.

Comment: Could you kindly amend your question with the Veins version you are using? I am guessing Veins 4.5, but I'm not too sure

Comment: Done Dr. @ChristophSommer. I'm creating a new mobility class inheriting TraCIMobility in order to change the updateDisplayString() behavior but I still don't get the propose of "moduleDisplayString" parameter. Could you explain that?

Comment: Thanks! You're absolutely correct in your assumptions about the `moduleDisplayString` parameter. Also, I found that setting this parameter is confirmed to not work in Veins 4.3, 4.4, and 4.5. I've heard that a fix is on its way, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a bug. In the latest releases Veins have been extended to enable the possibility of instantiating different module types for different SUMO vehicle types. For example you can use

```
*.manager.moduleType = "vtypeauto=Car vtypehuman=HumanCar"
*.manager.moduleName = "vtypeauto=node vtypehuman=human"
```

to instantiate the SUMO vtype `vtypeauto` with the `Car.ned` module and refer to it in the configuration with `node` (e.g., `*.node[*].mobility.z = 1.895`), while instantiating the vtype `vtypehuman` with the `HumanCar.ned` module and allowing you to configure it using `human`.

The bug is due to the syntax, as this feature uses an `=` sign to split between key and value pairs. The same holds for the `moduleDisplayString` parameter, so the parser does not work.

I prepared a patch where single quotes (`'`) can be used to protect display strings. In your specific case, your configuration becomes

```
*.manager.moduleDisplayString = "'i=misc/sun;is=vs'"
```

so the parser knows how to properly read the parameter. I tried also this configuration

```
*.manager.moduleType = "vtypeauto=Car vtypehuman=HumanCar"
*.manager.moduleName = "vtypeauto=node vtypehuman=human"
*.manager.moduleDisplayString = "vtypeauto='i=misc/sun;is=vs' vtypehuman='i=abstract/penguin'"
```

and this is the result

[image: Simulation screenshot]

You can see the sun image for one type of vehicle and the penguin for the other. As you correctly pointed out, Veins currently displays a box to highlight the car. This will most probably be removed soon, or changed with a better icon (e.g., an actual car icon).

I will prepare a patch and this should soon be published online on the github repo of Veins. In the meanwhile, I am copy-pasting here the snippet for you, so you can continue working without waiting for the official release. What you have to do is add the following function just before the function `TraCIScenarioManager::parseMappings` in `TraCIScenarioManager.cpp`.

```
std::vector<std::string> getMapping(std::string el) {

    //search for string protection characters '
    char protection = '\'';
    size_t first = el.find(protection);
    size_t second;
    size_t eq;
    std::string type, value;
    std::vector<std::string> mapping;

    if (first == std::string::npos) {
        //there's no string protection, simply split by '='
        cStringTokenizer stk(el.c_str(), "=");
        mapping = stk.asVector();
    }
    else {
        //if there's string protection, we need to find a matching delimiter
        second = el.find(protection, first + 1);
        //ensure that a matching delimiter exists, and that it is at the end
        if (second == std::string::npos || second != el.size() - 1)
            throw cRuntimeError("invalid syntax for mapping \"%s\"", el.c_str());

        //take the value of the mapping as the text within the quotes
        value = el.substr(first + 1, second - first - 1);

        if (first == 0) {
            //if the string starts with a quote, there's only the value
            mapping.push_back(value);
        }
        else {
            //search for the equal sign
            eq = el.find('=');
            //this must be the character before the quote
            if (eq == std::string::npos || eq != first - 1) {
                throw cRuntimeError("invalid syntax for mapping \"%s\"", el.c_str());
            }
            else {
                type = el.substr(0, eq);
            }
            mapping.push_back(type);
            mapping.push_back(value);
        }
    }
    return mapping;
}
```

Then change the following two lines inside the `TraCIScenarioManager::parseMappings` function

```
cStringTokenizer typeMappingTz(typeMapping.c_str(), "=");
std::vector<std::string> mapping = typeMappingTz.asVector();
```

with

```
std::vector<std::string> mapping = getMapping(typeMapping);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I'll try it!